# Need help Identifying Font

Tags: fonts, font-identification, font-recommendation, web-fonts, font-design

I am trying to identify this font name from the last few days. 
Can someone help me, please?

[image: Hi]

Answer (score -1):

That would be Futura Heavy. If you have Adobe CC you can find it on their fonts page!

Comment: it's not Heavy, look closely. But you got the font family right.

Answer (score -1):

That is actually [Futura Bold](https://www.fonts.com/font/linotype/futura/bold) with some bevel effect applied.

[image: Futura Bold]